# Update to WordPress 4.9.2, but have heavily customized theme

Tags: customization, updates

My site (hosted on Wordpress.org) was heavily customized with a ton of CSS specifics done to the WordPress theme. This was done by the designer before me, and still trying to figure out what he did. In the meantime, we have a version update available to move to WordPress 4.9.2. I want to update our site asap to keep in line with the most current WordPress software, but any idea how the customizations may be effected during this update? Is it one of those things where I should update on a Sunday and monitor the site with fingers crossed? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Ideally you would update in a local environment to see what changes does it make to your site, and only if everything is tested and ok, then update the live site. And ideally you would have a backup of everything before any of that.

Comment: Do you have a custom theme, a modified theme or a child theme?

Comment: This is a child theme of Proxima.

Comment: The guy before me, I was told, essentially "jail broke" the theme and heavily customized it, so typical advice and forums I am holding off on being that we are so customized.

Comment: By local environment, do you mind clarifying? Additionally, there is a backup selection under "theme setting". Is that what you are referring to? That was my first thought as I am looking into this.

Comment: Local environment is web server on your personal computer. Depending on your OS it could be mampp, xampp, lampp, wamp or some other program, or a virtualized machine. You would install a new wordpress install (you can try 4.9.2 and older too) and move the theme there, and see what happens. But if you are not familiar with the term local environment, this may not be the best option for you, because there are a lot of small things you must config in order for the site to work exactly like on the one on wordpress.org. See **migrating wordpress**. And by backup I mean theme, database, everything.

Answer (score 1):

Updating WP Core should not affect the theme, but if the previous person edited theme files directly, updating the theme itself would. Copying everything to a local or staging site, then running the updates one by one and checking a few key pages of the site, should highlight any major problems and is a best practice no matter what type of themes and plugins you're running.

If the last person edited theme files directly, it would be best to download an unaltered copy of the same version of that theme, and use a file comparison tool to identify which files they changed. (Example: BeyondCompare, or use version control to commit the last version in production - then commit the latest version of the parent theme, and you can then see exactly which files have changed and how.)

From there, you can then create a child theme that contains only those modifications. Then, you can update the parent theme, double-check everything, and potentially just make a tweak or two at most on your new child theme to bring it up to par.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress.org does not host websites.

The best way to find out is to create a fresh install of WordPress on your local machine and install the theme in question to see if anything breaks. IF not, your theme is compatible with 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation of theme being highly customized, it would definitely break the site. Following is the way to handle your upgrade.

- Install fresh new version of wordpress 4.9.2 on different sub directory like example.com/newsite.
- Move your theme and plugin one-by-one and keeping in track of what you are doing and when your site started throwing errors.
- Fix those errors
- Once all fixed, move it to the live environment.

OR

Install fresh new wordpress, choose some nearby premium template, migrate your data to this installation, have some customization made on the theme (FOLLOW WORDPRESS STANDARD PRACTICES), and then be done with it.

This is would be quick as you don't need to face much of the error.